# Silverlight app settings to write files

Tags: vb.net, silverlight-5.0

I have developed a test application in silverlight which can read a text file. I added functionality to write a simple text file. I uploaded the program to Windows Server 2008 R2.

When I run the silverlight program it does read a text file but it is unable to create/write any files. In that folder properties (on server) I think I have given write permission. I am using silverlight 5 and language is vb.net.

Can you tell me what should I do or permissions that I need to give and how so that the program can write to files in server.

Thank you,

Cheers,
GR

Comment: Are you sure you've given write permissions on the server? This is all you should need to do. Can you post the code that writes the file - there may be an problem with that.

Comment: Does your app have elevated permissions?  Is it an out-of-browser app?